# exact event handler after choosing value in autosuggested text field jquery

Tags: jquery, events, printing, handler

I have written a autosuggestion textfield. Now after choosing the value, I need to alert that value.[image]
Please see the picture. If I type `Ma` then in `Math` is one of my suggestion. So when I click on that Math, the text field should be override to Math. Upto this is fine. 
User can choose from the suggestion or he can write Math letter by letter in the textfield. According to that value another drop box will be created by ajax. 
Now please let me know, what will be the actual event handler function? If I use keyup() then only Ma is printing, If use change then it is happening the same. Please let me know the correct one.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function suggest(inputString,cat_id){
        if(inputString.length == 0) {
            $('#suggestions').fadeOut();
        } else {
        $('#issue_book_title').addClass('load');
            $.post("<?php echo $base_url?>all_book_title.php?cat_id="+cat_id+"&title_string="+inputString, function(data){
                if(data.length >0) {
                    $('#suggestions').fadeIn();
                    $('#suggestionsList').html(data);
                    $('#issue_book_title').removeClass('load');
                }
            });
        }
    }

    function fill(thisValue) {
        $('#issue_book_title').val(thisValue);
        setTimeout("$('#suggestions').fadeOut();", 600);
    }
</script>

<input type="text" name="issue_book_title" id="issue_book_title" value="" class="textbox_small"  onkeyup="suggest(this.value,document.getElementById('book_cat').value);" />
<input type="hidden" name="hide_book_cat" id="hide_book_cat" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="hide_book_title" id="hide_book_title" value="" />
<div class="suggestionsBox" id="suggestions" style="display: none;"> 
<div class="suggestionList" id="suggestionsList"> &nbsp; </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#issue_book_title').on('change',function(event){
                   alert(event.target.value);
                   //alert("Proceed");
                    var book_title = $('#issue_book_title').val();

                   $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url : "<?php echo $base_url?>issue_book_author.php?book_title="+book_title,
                       success:function(res){
                        $('#populate_book_author').html(res);
                       }
                    });
               });
</script>
```

and in the all_book_title.php file I just fetch the data from mysql DB

```
include('config_db_ajax.php'); //db connection file
$title = $_REQUEST['title_string'];
$cat_id = ($_REQUEST['cat_id']!= '')?$_REQUEST['cat_id']:'';

$sql = "SELECT title FROM book_details WHERE title LIKE '%".$title."%'";
if($cat_id != ''){
    $sql .= " AND cat_id=".$cat_id;
}
$query = mysql_query($sql);
echo '<ul>';
while($res = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    echo '<li onClick="fill(\''.$res['title'].'\');"><input type="hidden">'.$res['title'].'</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I can update my question with my code. Is it okay if I do that?

Comment: Please do so, that way we can identify what autocomplete plugin you're using and if it has an `.on('select')` event.

Comment: please check my updated question. Also if I add an dummy alert and print sme value then its working.